# Angular 4 Component Won't Import Typing

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple component that won't compile because of a typing issue.

**Component**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { DriveItem } from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types';
import { getType, DriveItemType } from '../../helpers/graphItem.helper';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-selected-item',
    templateUrl: './selected-item.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./selected-item.component.scss']
})
export class SelectedItemComponent {

    @Input() selectedItem: DriveItem;
    @Input() deselectItem: Function;

    constructor() { }

    itemType(item: DriveItem): DriveItemType {
        return getType(item);
    }
}
```

The error is happening with the `DriveItem` type. I've used this elsewhere in my project with no issues, but for some reason it will not resolve correctly in this component.

**Error**

```
ERROR in ./src/app/components/selected-item/selected-item.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types' in '/Users/jack/repos/project/src/app/components/selected-item'
resolve '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types' in '/Users/jack/repos/project/src/app/components/selected-item'
Parsed request is a module
using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src/app/components/selected-item)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
after using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src/app/components/selected-item)
    resolve as module
    /Users/jack/repos/project/src/app/components/selected-item/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    /Users/jack/repos/project/src/app/components/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    /Users/jack/repos/project/src/app/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    /Users/jack/repos/project/src/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    /Users/jack/repos/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    /Users/jack/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    /Users/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    looking for modules in /Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules
        using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
        using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types/package.json (relative path: .)
            no extension
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types is not a file
            .ts
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.ts doesn't exist
            .js
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.js doesn't exist
            as directory
            existing directory
                using path: /Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types/index
                using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types/package.json (relative path: ./index)
                    no extension
                    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                    /Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types/index doesn't exist
                    .ts
                    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                    /Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types/index.ts doesn't exist
                    .js
                    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                    /Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types/index.js doesn't exist
    looking for modules in /Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules
        using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
        using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types/package.json (relative path: .)
            no extension
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types is not a file
            .ts
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.ts doesn't exist
            .js
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.js doesn't exist
            as directory
            existing directory
                using path: /Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types/index
                using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types/package.json (relative path: ./index)
                    no extension
                    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                    /Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types/index doesn't exist
                    .ts
                    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                    /Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types/index.ts doesn't exist
                    .js
                    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                    /Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types/index.js doesn't exist
    looking for modules in /Users/jack/repos/project/src
        using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src)
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src)
        using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types)
            no extension
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types doesn't exist
            .ts
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.ts doesn't exist
            .js
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.js doesn't exist
            as directory
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types doesn't exist
    looking for modules in /Users/jack/repos/project/src
        using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src)
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src)
        using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types)
            no extension
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types doesn't exist
            .ts
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.ts doesn't exist
            .js
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.js doesn't exist
            as directory
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types doesn't exist
    looking for modules in /Users/jack/repos/project/src
        using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src)
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src)
        using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types)
            no extension
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types doesn't exist
            .ts
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.ts doesn't exist
            .js
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.js doesn't exist
            as directory
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types doesn't exist
    looking for modules in /Users/jack/repos/project/src
        using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src)
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src)
        using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types)
            no extension
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types doesn't exist
            .ts
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.ts doesn't exist
            .js
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.js doesn't exist
            as directory
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types doesn't exist
    looking for modules in /Users/jack/repos/project/src
        using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src)
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src)
        using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types)
            no extension
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types doesn't exist
            .ts
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.ts doesn't exist
            .js
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.js doesn't exist
            as directory
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types doesn't exist
    looking for modules in /Users/jack/repos/project/src
        using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src)
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src)
        using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types)
            no extension
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types doesn't exist
            .ts
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.ts doesn't exist
            .js
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.js doesn't exist
            as directory
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types doesn't exist
    looking for modules in /Users/jack/repos/project/src
        using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src)
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src)
        using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types)
            no extension
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types doesn't exist
            .ts
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.ts doesn't exist
            .js
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.js doesn't exist
            as directory
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types doesn't exist
    looking for modules in /Users/jack/repos/project/src
        using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src)
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src)
        using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types)
            no extension
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types doesn't exist
            .ts
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.ts doesn't exist
            .js
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.js doesn't exist
            as directory
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types doesn't exist
    looking for modules in /Users/jack/repos/project/src
        using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src)
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src)
        using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types)
            no extension
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types doesn't exist
            .ts
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.ts doesn't exist
            .js
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.js doesn't exist
            as directory
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types doesn't exist
    looking for modules in /Users/jack/repos/project/src
        using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src)
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src)
        using description file: /Users/jack/repos/project/package.json (relative path: ./src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types)
            no extension
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types doesn't exist
            .ts
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.ts doesn't exist
            .js
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.js doesn't exist
            as directory
            /Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types doesn't exist
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/app/components/selected-item/node_modules]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/app/components/node_modules]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/app/node_modules]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/node_modules]
[/Users/jack/repos/node_modules]
[/Users/jack/node_modules]
[/Users/node_modules]
[/node_modules]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.ts]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.js]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types/index]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types/index.ts]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types/index.js]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.ts]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.js]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types/index]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types/index.ts]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types/index.js]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.ts]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.js]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.ts]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.js]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.ts]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.js]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.ts]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.js]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.ts]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.js]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.ts]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.js]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.ts]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.js]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.ts]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.js]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.ts]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.js]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.ts]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types.js]
[/Users/jack/repos/project/src/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types]
@ ./src/app/components/selected-item/selected-item.component.ts 11:0-61
@ ./src/app/app.module.ts
@ ./src/main.ts
@ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

I thought that it might be because I added a new directory called `components` and this file lives there, but I have no way of knowing if that's the issue.

**Folder Structure**

```
/src
    /app
        /components
            /selected-item
                - selected-item.component.ts <-- This file will not resolve DriveItem type
        /helpers
            - graphItem.helper.ts <-- DriveItem type works fine here
        /pages
            /home
                - home.component.ts <-- DriveItem type also works fine here.
```

So far I've tried the following:

- Install the latest version of Angular CLI
- Deleted node modules, cleaned cache, re-installed.
- Attempted different variations of the the import `* as MicrosoftGraph` versus `{ DriveItem } from`
- Removed the types and just use `any`. It's worth noting that I can import the `DriveItem` type, but the compilation only fails if I try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import in your app module ?

```
import { DriveItem } from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types';

// other imports 
@NgModule({
imports: [DriveItem],
...
})
```

Comment: `DriveItem` isn't a NgModule so I'm unable to add it to the imports array.